# JQuery two way binding without Knockout or Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to do a two way binding with Javascript and JQuery without using any library like AngularJS or Knockout, in a ASP.NET MVC and Web API application.
I'm using the MVC Views only for display purpose, and in the MVC view, for example Index, to bind the data with an Web API controller, say **Get** and display the results in there using Javascript and JQuery. For example, if I have the following model:

```
public class User(){
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

The models in my project are generated using the Entity Framework. So this model could correspond to a database table which have the following data:

```
Id    | Name   |
1     | a      |
2     | b      |
```

My MVC controller for displaying the users will just return a View:

```
public ActionResult Index(){
    return View();
}
```

My Web API controller could look something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers(){
    var users = from row in Users select row;
    ...
    return users;
}
```

**The Question**
How can I use Javascript and JQuery to display the users in the **Index** View of the MVC Controller, by getting the data from the Web Api controller using the **two way binding** without using Knockout, AngularJS, etc? Can you please provide an working example?

Thanks!

Comment: You would need to use Ajax

Comment: ok, I can use Ajax, but can you give me an example, please?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are tying to use the wrong tool for the task.
JQuery is a tool for dom manipulation and does not provide two-way binding.

While you can display & read data via e.g. .text() or .val() (http://api.jquery.com/val/) you would have to handle the changes manually.

You might want to consider a library with native two-way-binding, if you really want to use this feature.